# How to see the current value of a setting in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS code how can I see the current value of a specify setting variable?

For example: I have the *Code Runner* extension installed. In the Feature contribution page I saw that it has a setting variable

`code-runner.executorMap` (Set the executor of each language.)

How can  see the *current* value of this setting? Is there a way to display this value? Or do I need to trawl through the different JSON setting files (Default/User/Workspace) to then determine its current value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** You can view the value of *many* specific setting variables via the settings editor in VS Code. There's a [web page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) describing all aspects of that, including settings for extensions.

To modify user settings, you'll use the Settings editor to review and change VS Code settings.

To open the Settings editor, use the following VS Code menu command:

- On Windows/Linux - File > Preferences > Settings
- On macOS - Code > Preferences > Settings

You can also open the Settings editor from the Command Palette (⇧⌘P) with Preferences: Open Settings or use the keyboard shortcut (⌘,).

**(2)** However *some* settings - like the one you mention (`code-runner.executorMap`) - cannot directly be viewed in the settings editor. They just show up with a "Edit in settings.json" link.

When you click that link VS Code will possibly add the default value for that variable to your user or workspace settings file. Be aware of this.

Comment: Ok, thanks for spelling it out. That's probably just what it is: You can't see just the current value of a setting variable easily, you rather need to do the following: First open the workspace settings and search there for your variable; if not found, you need to open the user settings, search there again, if not found, you need finally open the default settings and search through that list. Am I correct? (Feels pretty cumbersome to me!)

Comment: It's all in one place actually (except for the plain settings files). You can switch between different settings scopes (user, workspace and sometimes folder), to see settings which are in set in either of them. For just reading a setting use the default settings view/scope (user), which gives a hint if a setting has been changed in any of the other scopes.

Comment: Makes sense, Mike. However some settings are a bit problematic when they just show up as "Edit in settings.json", because when you view them in the settings.json file the default value might be injected by VS Code. Updated the answer to make readers aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration.

```
const myWorkbench = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('myWorkbench')
const yourConfigValue = myWorkbench.get('yourConfigValue')
```

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. Where do I enter this code snippet? And how does the snippet displays the value in the UI?

Comment: @halloleo This code shows how to get the value. What else do you need? How you display the value in the UI is completely up to you.

Comment: @MikeLischke Well, I am a _user_ of VS Code for programming in Java and Haskell, and just want to find out what value some settings have... But maybe there is no way to see a setting in VS Code, only the effect of a setting?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).